# Listen to HDMI plugged and unplugged events on Android TV

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, android-tv

I need to receive the HDMI state events for my Android TV app.

I found this code in several places:

```
public class HdmiListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String HDMIINTENT = "android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent receivedIt) {
        String action = receivedIt.getAction();

        if (action.equals(HDMIINTENT)) {
            boolean state = receivedIt.getBooleanExtra("state", false);
        }
    }
}
```

with this in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="[package].HdmiListener" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but **it does not work**. The broadcast receiver never gets triggered.

I did some digging through AOSP and other projects and were able to come up with a more complete version of the manifest entry:

```
    <permission android:name="android.permission.TV_INPUT_HARDWARE"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
        tools:ignore="SignatureOrSystemPermissions" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_TV_INPUT"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
        tools:ignore="SignatureOrSystemPermissions" />

    <receiver android:name="[package].HdmiListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TVOUT_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but **is still does not work** :-(

So, my question is - **did anybody get this to actually work**? Or is it a system-level-only feature, as the permissions would suggest?

Comment: Could you please provide the error logs?

Comment: Hey :-) There are no error logs. The BroadcastReceiver is not triggered :-(

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oleynikd/1065521ee3236a60b804ad063020021f

Answer (score 0):

`android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED` has `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT` flag. From the comment in Intent.java:

```
 FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT

 * If set, when sending a broadcast before boot has completed only
 * registered receivers will be called -- no BroadcastReceiver components
 * will be launched.  Sticky intent state will be recorded properly even
 * if no receivers wind up being called.  If {@link #FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY}
 * is specified in the broadcast intent, this flag is unnecessary.
 *
 * <p>This flag is only for use by system sevices as a convenience to
 * avoid having to implement a more complex mechanism around detection
 * of boot completion.
```

At least, receiver should be registered by calling `registerReceiver`.